# Python3 failing big division?

Tags: python

Straight to the point...

By using a website like [this](http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/100digitbigintcalculator.htm)

I can perform the division

```
521867179249063104431771532319014802773340606735040694338278785354627691365941164783141053870302908448515826940518729762675345436448874794321999883308020735915961604709858819996385388187935859640654596335746881134780531452843909715448234514762462143856204913946601253808724104934316876333775771684458187648281797991584927160155639951080324566002195236407608721860154059967443327355489731291105400056189691357913203235154988726468260641765071983123570916184780526935910110174741817085928010767101123823291935770762480197142805725028939936563200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

over

```
788657867364790503552363213932185062295135977687173263294742533244359449963403342920304284011984623904177212138919638830257642790242637105061926624952829931113462857270763317237396988943922445621451664240254033291864131227428294853277524242407573903240321257405579568660226031904170324062351700858796178922222789623703897374720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

which becomes

```
661715556065930365627163346132458831897321703017638669364788134708891795956726411057801285583913163781806953211915554723373931451847059830252175887712457307547649354135460619296383882957897161889636280577155889117185
```

I perform the same operation in python, I get

```
661715556065930359197186982471212353583889520695638616110586544529019733927881270928911271177789723412658535123976620081599644618300461938312003378924403625257962695989873267296634026151114440358844358704274123784192
```

The first 16 numbers are correct, the rest is just a mess. How could this be? I'm using `int(a/b)` to remove the scientific notification `+e**`, perhaps this is causing it...

Comment: `int(a/b)` isn't how you do integer division. By the time `int` gets called, the damage is already done.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Python 3.4.4 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:54:04) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> a = 521867179249063104431771532319014802773340606735040694338278785354627691365941164783141053870302908448515826940518729762675345436448874794321999883308020735915961604709858819996385388187935859640654596335746881134780531452843909715448234514762462143856204913946601253808724104934316876333775771684458187648281797991584927160155639951080324566002195236407608721860154059967443327355489731291105400056189691357913203235154988726468260641765071983123570916184780526935910110174741817085928010767101123823291935770762480197142805725028939936563200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    >>> b = 788657867364790503552363213932185062295135977687173263294742533244359449963403342920304284011984623904177212138919638830257642790242637105061926624952829931113462857270763317237396988943922445621451664240254033291864131227428294853277524242407573903240321257405579568660226031904170324062351700858796178922222789623703897374720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    >>> a // b
    661715556065930365627163346132458831897321703017638669364788134708891795956726411057801285583913163781806953211915554723373931451847059830252175887712457307547649354135460619296383882957897161889636280577155889117185
```

In **python3**, **integer-division** is done by `//` operator.

Here's the relevant [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

Comment: But why doesn't a single / work? If my 2 numbers wouldn't return an int I would not want to use the //?

Comment: Read the link and think about the comment by @user2357112. A single `/` is just a division in fp-arithmetic, which may lose information. Your case, when the div has a remainder can be handled with [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#divmod).

Comment: @user1768788: The online calculator you linked to also gives integer-only results. They give the specific example that dividing 14 by 5 will produce 2. If you want real-valued results, you're going to have to go learn about the limits of real number representations, and you'll probably look at a bunch of things like rational and symbolic representations before learning that you have to make sacrifices *somewhere*. It's disappointing, I know.